# How to set linker's OutputFile (in .vcxproj) from external list

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-2017-build-tools, vcxproj

I have a bunch of C++ projects (.vcxproj) for VS2017, which produce dynamic libraries (DLL), which are handled like "plugins" (i.e. they are loaded dynamically by the application).

Occasionally I want to change the produced DLLs names based on some list in text file (the format may be changed):

```
ProjName1;DLL1
ProjName2;DLL2
...
```

The first column specifies the project name (`$(ProjectName)`) and the second is for desired DLL name (`$(TargetName)`).

I want this file to be parsed at build-time, so each read DLL name goes into `$(OutputFile)` of the appropriate project.

For instance, `ProjName1.vcxproj` will have following fragment (at build time):

```
<Link>
  <OutputFile>$(OutDir)DLL1$(TargetExt)</OutputFile>
</Link>
```

I guess, certain capabilities of `msbuild` can be utilized for this (e.g., [ReadLinesFromFile task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/readlinesfromfile-task) and [FindInList task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/findinlist-task)), but I'm not sure how to put these pieces together).

There are some examples of such automation to consider, though I doubt they are relevant to .vcxproj format:

- [MSBuild ReadLinesFromFile all text on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272518/msbuild-readlinesfromfile-all-text-on-one-line)
- [Read text file and split every line in MSBuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460495/read-text-file-and-split-every-line-in-msbuild)
- [Used ReadLinesFromFile to make version in separate file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6295823/536172)

The straightforward approach is to modify content of each .vcxproj-file to match the list (either manually, or with some script).

Are there any other options?

---

**Update 1**: I've managed to implement a partial solution, which is based on a separate file with DLL name (*module name*) for each project (refer to [Property Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions) for more hints).

With property sheets it was easy in my case to 'inject' the fix into all projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_MODULE.name')">
    <ModuleName>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\_MODULE.name'))</ModuleName>
    <TargetName>$(ModuleName)</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

Though it works quite good, the approach doesn't meet my needs perfectly - I'd like to have all module names in one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations and tryouts I've finally managed to make a working solution for my case. Basically it is built on top of my previous partial solution by using magic powers of [Regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex). The hint how to handle regex in my context was found in [another answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17201084/536172).

I've also tuned the list format a bit to my taste:

```
DLL1=ProjName1
DLL2=ProjName2
...
```

I've placed the changes in the property sheet, so they can be easily picked up by all dependent projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
...
  <PropertyGroup Condition="exists('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\_MODULES.txt')">
    <ModulesNames>$([System.IO.File]::ReadAllText('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)..\_MODULES.txt'))</ModulesNames>
    <ModuleName>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(ModulesNames), '\W?(\w*)\W?=\W?$(MSBuildProjectName)\W?').get_Groups().get_Item(1))</ModuleName>
    <TargetName>$(ModuleName)</TargetName>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
</Project>
```

If the project isn't listed in `_MODULES.txt`, its `$(TargetName)` isn't affected.

If you see `$(ModuleName)` in the project settings, then everything is tuned correctly:
[image: VS2017 project settings]

The solution seems to work fine except for **one minor drawback**: the build system (VS2017 v.15.9.15) is quite "lazy" in detecting changed in `_MODULES.txt` while the solution is open, so you'll have to close it and reopen. And chances are high the rebuild will be needed after you change the list.

Comment: Hi AntonK, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as answer and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)