# Compiler Additional Options computed in a custom Target

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task, compiler-options

I have a msbuild custom Target and a Task computing a Value. 
The Task will output the Value as Property.
This Property I would like to uses as Additional Option to the Compiler call.

But the Property is empty when used as Additional Option.

My ***.targets** File looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="GetBranchName_TASK" TaskFactory="CodeTaskFactory" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0.dll" >
    <ParameterGroup>
        <sPath ParameterType="System.String" Required="true" />
        <sBranchName ParameterType="System.String" Output="true" />
    </ParameterGroup>
    <Task>
      <Code Type="Fragment" Language="cs">
        <![CDATA[
            ... some Code ...
        ]]>
      </Code>
    </Task>
  </UsingTask>

  <Target Name="GetBranchName_TARGET">
    <GetBranchName_TASK sPath="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)">
      <Output PropertyName="BranchName" TaskParameter="sBranchName" />
    </GetBranchName_TASK>
    <Message Importance="High" Text="BranchName = $(BranchName)" />
  </Target>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <BuildDependsOn>
        GetBranchName_TARGET;
        $(BuildDependsOn);
    </BuildDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

My ***.props** File is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Label="Configuration">
    ... some Properties here ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <Import Project="IRSGetBranchName.targets" /> 
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalOptions>/DBRANCHNAME=$(BranchName) /DMORE=BAR</AdditionalOptions>
    <ClCompile>
  <ItemDefinitionGroup>
</Project>
```

This ***.props*** File then is imported into several **.vcxproj**

The Value printed as Message in my *GetBranchName_TARGET* is correct as expected (showing the correct TFS-Branch Name). 
But when looking at *Detailed Build Output*, the Value seems empty:

```
1>ClCompile
1>    ..\FOO.cpp
1>        AdditionalOptions = /DBRANCHNAME= /DMORE=BAR
```

I tried for hours but found no solution and I really hope someone help whats wrong here ...

a) Is the Property **BranchName** not available globally? I tried to print the Property from other custom Targets and it worked well!

b) Or is the *ClCompile.AdditionalOptions* evaluated/build before my Target is excuted? In this case how can I re-evaluate?

c) ...

I'am very thankful for any Input.

Comment: a) yes it is b) yes, because it's defined globally outside of a target it's evaluated before your target runs, and that's your problem. Im not 100% sure but putting the itemDefinitionGroup with ClCompile *inside* the GetBranchName_TARGET should work

Comment: @stijn: Thank you. Your comment targeted me to the perfect solution. Just like the Answer by stukselbax. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be familiar with the msbuild evaluation process, as described [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735645248):

> When the MSBuild engine begins to process a build file, it is evaluated in a top-down fashion in a multi-pass manner. These passes are described in order in the following list:
>
> 1. Load all environment and global properties, and toolset properties. In Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, for example, C++ defines several properties in the MSBuild 4.0 toolset.
> 2. Evaluate properties and process imports as encountered
> 3. Evaluate item definitions
> 4. Evaluate items
> 5. Evaluate using tasks
> 6. Start build and reading targets

So, in your case, the `ItemDefinitionGroup` for `ClCompile` has been evaluated before the **GetBranchName_TARGET** has been executed. So, it is empty by design.

In order to achieve the desired behavior, you should Add the following:

```
<Target Name="GetBranchName_TARGET">
  <GetBranchName_TASK sPath="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)">
    <Output PropertyName="BranchName" TaskParameter="sBranchName" />
  </GetBranchName_TASK>
  <Message Importance="High" Text="BranchName = $(BranchName)" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile>
      <AdditionalOptions>/DBRANCHNAME=$(BranchName) /DMORE=BAR</AdditionalOptions>
    </ClCompile>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

You can use a `Condition` attribute in the ClCompile in order to include only your sources, for example. Actually, what you are looking for is the feature to modify [item metadata after it was declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841913/modify-msbuild-itemgroup-metadata).